# How do I install a shoulder belt if it already has a lap belt?

Tags: seat-belt

Have a classic car with a bench that only has a lap belt.

Instead of replacing the whole belt system (newer 3 point seat belt), are there any options to install just the upper body restraint, in addition to what is already there? Or is this a sloppy solution?

Comment: What is your specific application. Aftermarket suppliers usually have a complete 3 point seat belt. I can better answer your question with the make model info

Comment: @Larry: it's a mid 60's c10 with what I believe is a mid 70's bench and laps belts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weasco sells retro fit belts with detailed instruction for 3 point belts
http://www.wescoperformance.com/retrofit-seat-belts-shoulder-mt-door.html They include models for convertables and sedans. You can select just the shoulder belt add on or a new complete belt system.